# Tricks to emulating a Firefox fast-startup without using third parties?

Tags: windows, firefox, performance, browser, notification-area

(Windows 11) Firefox starts up significantly slow (when there aren't any windows already open) compared to Chrome and Edge, which seem almost instant. (I've tried without any add-ons/extensions, so that isn't the problem).

Are there any tricks to emulating a Firefox fast-startup without using third-parties? I can't find any solution, but I was thinking there should be some way to place Firefox in the system tray, or to make a background Firefox process that's always running.

Comment: Instead, why not just try to solve the actual problem? Try clearing cache, history or even refreshing the Firefox profile.

Comment: Does it happen when you [Start Firefox in Safe Mode](https://www.wikihow.com/Start-Firefox-in-Safe-Mode) ?

Comment: My Firefox starts up almost instantly and is only noticeably slow when there are updates or certain website tabs are being loaded. I can't remember what websites caused it to be slow but as a first try you should start with a clean session. Have you tried [refreshing firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) to clear settings and restore performance. Note this may remove extensions, as well as other data, which may be a source of your problems.

Comment: You might set Firefox to *Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed*. Here are some hints on speeding startup: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/speed-up-firefox/ and (older) https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/firefox-browser-start-faster/ That said, I notice FFox (and LibreOffice) start much faster in Linux than under Windows.  Perhaps Windows does things to optimize startup of MS apps?

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried many ways to fix performance, so that's why I'm hoping to use a system tray solution like some other apps use. My browser settings already clear everything on exit, and I recently confirmed that a clean Firefox had the same issue for me. I've also gone through every setting, and I've implemented all of the `about:config` optimizations I've seen.

Comment: Try adding Firefox to exception on Defender, and also try running in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

If the storage device containing the current Firefox profile is slow or is being used by other processes, Firefox may be a bit slow to open.

One solution to this is to set up a RAM drive that contains your Firefox profile(s).  If properly configured, this drive will operate faster than any other drive in your system.

Note that RAM drives are volatile, meaning they get deleted when the power is removed.  As such, you will likely want to use one that backs up its contents to non-volatile (permanent) storage.  Else, you can write a simple routine that will perform this backup activity.